# how to extends two class Android activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to-->

class mainactivity extends ListActivity,MapActivity{
}

It's possible???

class mainactivity extends Any java class1,Any java Class2{
}

anyone possible??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can't . **java doesn't let that type of polymorphism** . You must use implements for interfaces .

Read [this](http://home.cogeco.ca/~ve3ll/jatutor5.htm)

Comment: android is based in java and has a JVM , it's the same for that. You can't it in Android

Comment: you're wellcome , and please tick :)

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible because you can not extend more than one class but you can implement more than one interface which is not of any use here.

Answer (score 2):

no its not possible because in core java  a class can only inherit one class .
In c++ its possible to inherit more than one class. So thats why its not possible

Answer (score 2):

Java  does not support multiple inheritance, more than one class can not be extended
but  there is solution , but in your case i think you can use like this:

```
  class MapActivity extends Service{
   ...
  }

 class mainactivity extends ListActivity{

  MapActivity mapActivity= new MapActivity();
 }
```